# Constraining all coefficients to be equal, mlogit, Stata

Tags: constraints, stata, mlogit

I have a multinomial logit model that I want to estimate with mlogit. I want to constraint the coefficients on one of the independent variables (but not the rest) to be equal across all alternatives. I have tried the following constraints, but always get an error from Stata, "constraint number # caused error r(198))":

```
constraint define 1 [1=2]var_name  
constraint define 2 [1=3]var_name  
constraint define 3 [1=4]var_name  
constraint define 4 [1=5]var_name
```

OR

```
constraint define 1 [1]var_name = [2]var_name  
constraint define 2 [1]var_name = [3]var_name  
constraint define 3 [1]var_name = [4]var_name  
constraint define 4 [1]var_name = [5]var_name
```

There are 6 alternatives total, I use the 6th as base. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
webuse sysdsn1
tab insure
constraint 1 [Prepaid]age=[Uninsure]age
mlogit insure age male nonwhite i.site, base(1) constraint(1)
```

Comment: When I try this with the insurance data, it works, but with my data, I get an error (111).